# Why am I having a problem accessing a class in html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a developers' page in a website but I am encountering so problems.
As you can see below I am trying to detect if a user is hovering on a certain card(.card) to 3d flip it.

I have realized that when it works, I would have called the .container before it, and if I don't it does't do anything.

I have tried doing: .container .card:hover .cardFlip { /*code*/ } but it also didn't work!

```html
<div class="container">

    <!-- Joe's Card -->
    <div class="card" id="JoeGermany">
      <h2>Joe Germany</h2>
      <img src="JoeGermany.jpg" alt="Joe Germany" class="JoeImg">
    </div>

    <div class="cardFlip">
      <div class="left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container .card:hover {
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

This works! BUT!!

```css
.card:hover .cardFlip {
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-30deg);
}
```

This does't work!!

Thank you for any help in advance!
Please do not be too rough if I have missed a silly mistake because I am considered rather a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

`.card:hover .cardFlip`

doesn't work because `.cardFlip` is a **sibling** rather than a **descendant** element of `.card`.

To select `.cardFlip`, you need either:

- `.cardFlip`
- `.container .cardFlip`
- `.card:hover + .cardFlip`

etc.

Answer (score 1):

`.card:hover .cardFlip` means select all elements with the class `cardFlip` that are descendants of elements with the class `card` but with your hierarchy, this isn't true since the `cardFlip` div is a sibling of the `card` div, not a descendant.

Use `.card:hover + .cardFlip` instead, where `+` is the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

Comment: I see but one more question: I have 4 .cardFlip and when I tried you technique it only applied to one; so how can I fix it??

Comment: If all four cardFlips are siblings of the card, then use `~` instead of `+`

Comment: And sorry if I m asking a lot of questions but if there was a list of .cardFlip before .card or #JoeGermany; how could I access them??

Comment: There's no previous selector in CSS so you couldn't do that without JavaScript or a different HTML structure